# Is there a way to display other websites' images onto my own?

Tags: php

I'm making a website that grabs restaurant information from my database and displays it using PHP. I was wondering what the best way is to also grab the restaurants' images from their websites at the same time.

Thank you!

Comment: Download that file to your system: `file_put_contents('stolen-image.jpeg', file_get_contents('https://url-to-steal.com'))`

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not a great idea, unless you have explicit permission from those restaurants and/or the license-holders of the images you might be scraping.

If you scrape image URLs, you should be aware that hotlinking (loading an image hosted on a server that isn't yours) is frowned upon for a few reasons: you're possibly incurring them additional bandwidth costs, the image might be removed or have its URL changed which will then break your site, and so on.

Comment: I didn't know that...thank you! Guess I won't be doing that at all then.